# Are there any cons to using TO_<type> conversion instead of <type>_TO_<type>?

Tags: plc, twincat, structured-text, iec61131-3

TwinCAT and (I think so) every other IEC61131-3 language supports both conversion types `<type>_TO_<type>` and `TO_<type>`. I am wondering, is there any cons to using the latter, so `TO_<type>`? For example, I have a calculation and we all know, that typing the extra 5 letters makes or breaks your day ;)

```
nResult : INT;
fDivisor : REAL;

// Does this perform any slower, or are there any cons to using it like this?
nResult := TO_INT(32767.0/fDivisor);
nResult := REAL_TO_INT(32767.0/fDivisor);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used only the shorthand functions `TO_REAL()` etc. for last 1-2 years without any issues. They simplify the code alot and you don't need to write so much code.

I'm 99% sure that there are no cons / performance issues for the PLC runtime, as the compiler most probably just automatically checks the data type during compilation.

I haven't measured the performance, but the only downside I can think of is that the compiler needs to check some data types during compilation. However, when usin X_TO_Y() conversion, the compiler still checks the data type and gives a warning/error if needed.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't even know TO_ even existed (worked with Beckhoff PLCs for the past 3+ years haha) until not long ago when I was doing C# and switched to PLC the next day and did it automatically. Good to know, thanks.

Comment: Hopefully someone has better information for accepted answer :) But I certainly would use these instead of the "old ones". And the syntax is also more similar to C# Convert.ToInt32() etc.

Comment: Tn almost all practical cases performance differences, if any, are likely to be irrelevant.  I always use the X_TO_Y functions. The advantage is non-technical : it forces me to think about the conversion. Type conversions are not risk-free because they may compile yet fail at runtime (overflow). Forcing myself to really consider what is going on is a bonus for me, and typing a few more characters in exchange for a guarantee that I will actually pay attention is time saved, because avoiding one bug a year saves more time than any additional typing.

Comment: Fred you are absolutely right. Writing X_TO_Y makes you think twice.